# Quoting exclamation mark ("!) works with makeidx, but not with nomencl

Tags: indexing, nomencl

I know that, in order to use an exclamation mark inside an index or nomenclature entry, I need to quote it with `"`.

Now -- `makeidx` seems to work fine:

```
$ cat t.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\index{$n "! $, factorial of $n$}
\[
 n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
\]
\printindex
\end{document}

$ pdflatex t && makeindex t  && pdflatex t
```

will produce the PDF as expected, with the index at the end of the document.

However, if I use the `nomencl` package,

```
$ cat q.tex 

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$n "! $}{factorial of $n$}
\[
 n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
\]
\printnomenclature
\end{document}

$ pdflatex q && makeindex q.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o q.nls && pdflatex q
```

then the second call to `pdflatex` will fail, with

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))) (./q.aux)
(./q.nls
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5     \subitem
                 [{$n "
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on q.log.
```

Which is, as far as I remember, the exact error I would get if I had **not** quoted the exclamation mark!

Did I miss something, or is this a bug? If it is a bug in texlive (or in `nomencl`), how can I get more information so I can debug and report it?

I am using `texlive` version `2018.20190227-2` from Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your makindex style has

```
%% ---- for input file ----
keyword    "\\nomenclatureentry"
quote '%'
```

so you need `%` not `"`

[image]

The package already reads the argument verbatim, so `%` is not a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$n %! $}{factorial of $n$}
\[
 n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
\]
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  However... Is this something that is configurable? And why does the `"` quote work with makeidx and not with nomencl?

Comment: @Jay as I explain, `"` is the default quote character but the authors of `nomenc.ist` chose to change it to `%`.

Comment: I get it. I just realized that it is the file in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist`... Thank you again!